# What does the word "object" do in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, object

I'm confused about what the word "object" does in PHP for example:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
   $images[] = (object) $row;
}
```

What does "(object)" do? I've seen it occur multiple times and do not know it's purpose nor what it does, any explanation would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: It's a typecasting, basically doing the same sort of thing as `$x = (int)$var`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is used to place a variable inside an object in PHP.

You're using semi-deprecated functions btw, be careful with your useage, such as `mysql_fetch_oject()`.

Answer (score 4):

It is used to cast a variable (usually an array) into an object (stdClass).

Please don't follow this way of coding as it has many disadvantages and little benefits.

Also:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for
>   new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun
>   the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red
>   box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared
>   statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either
>   [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you
>   can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose.
>   If you care to learn, [here is good PDO
>   tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0):

(object) converts the variable to a variable with the datatype object.

e.g.

```
<?php
$car = array (
    'type' => 'Ford',
    'plate' => 'AZ-DF-123'
);

$p = (object) $car;
echo $p->type; // Will print 'Ford'
?>
```